JOLT transformation nested array and repeating keys
I'm having trouble with a JOLT specification and not sure where to go from here.
Original JSON:
{
  "readings": [
    {
      "meter": "02319771",
      "records": [
        {
          "timestamp": "28/06/2024 14:35:00",
          "values": {
            "Ah": 4350.947,
            "epoch_timestamp": 1719578227,
            "uniqueID": "12005"
          }
        },
        {
          "timestamp": "28/06/2024 15:00:00",
          "values": {
            "Ah": 4353.141,
            "epoch_timestamp": 1719579724,
            "uniqueID": "12005"
          }
        },
        {
          "timestamp": "28/06/2024 15:10:00",
          "values": {
            "Ah": 4354.023,
            "epoch_timestamp": 1719580326,
            "uniqueID": "12005"
          }
        },
        {
          "timestamp": "28/06/2024 15:15:00",
          "values": {
            "Ah": 4354.465,
            "epoch_timestamp": 1719580628,
            "uniqueID": "12005"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "meter": "02383367",
      "records": [
        {
          "timestamp": "28/06/2024 13:45:00",
          "values": {
            "Ah": 2969.499,
            "epoch_timestamp": 1719575171,
            "uniqueID": "12002"
          }
        },
        {
          "timestamp": "28/06/2024 14:00:00",
          "values": {
            "Ah": 2969.719,
            "epoch_timestamp": 1719576070,
            "uniqueID": "12002"
          }
        },
        {
          "timestamp": "28/06/2024 14:15:00",
          "values": {
            "Ah": 2969.938,
            "epoch_timestamp": 1719576969,
            "uniqueID": "12002"
          }
        },
        {
          "timestamp": "28/06/2024 14:35:00",
          "values": {
            "Ah": 2970.231,
            "epoch_timestamp": 1719578170,
            "uniqueID": "12002"
          }
        },
        {
          "timestamp": "28/06/2024 14:55:00",
          "values": {
            "Ah": 2970.524,
            "epoch_timestamp": 1719579369,
            "uniqueID": "12002"
          }
        },
        {
          "timestamp": "28/06/2024 15:10:00",
          "values": {
            "Ah": 2970.745,
            "epoch_timestamp": 1719580273,
            "uniqueID": "12002"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "meter": "02383567",
      "records": [
        {
          "timestamp": "28/06/2024 13:45:00",
          "values": {
            "Ah": 45957.805,
            "epoch_timestamp": 1719575210,
            "uniqueID": "12004"
          }
        },
        {
          "timestamp": "28/06/2024 14:35:00",
          "values": {
            "Ah": 46004.711,
            "epoch_timestamp": 1719578210,
            "uniqueID": "12004"
          }
        },
        {
          "timestamp": "28/06/2024 15:00:00",
          "values": {
            "Ah": 46028.102,
            "epoch_timestamp": 1719579708,
            "uniqueID": "12004"
          }
        },
        {
          "timestamp": "28/06/2024 15:10:00",
          "values": {
            "Ah": 46037.508,
            "epoch_timestamp": 1719580310,
            "uniqueID": "12004"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "meter": "02383735",
      "records": [
        {
          "timestamp": "28/06/2024 14:00:00",
          "values": {
            "Ah": 578668.312,
            "epoch_timestamp": 1719576015,
            "uniqueID": "11998"
          }
        },
        {
          "timestamp": "28/06/2024 14:15:00",
          "values": {
            "Ah": 578837.062,
            "epoch_timestamp": 1719576914,
            "uniqueID": "11998"
          }
        },
        {
          "timestamp": "28/06/2024 14:30:00",
          "values": {
            "Ah": 579006,
            "epoch_timestamp": 1719577815,
            "uniqueID": "11998"
          }
        },
        {
          "timestamp": "28/06/2024 14:35:00",
          "values": {
            "Ah": 579062.25,
            "epoch_timestamp": 1719578116,
            "uniqueID": "11998"
          }
        },
        {
          "timestamp": "28/06/2024 14:50:00",
          "values": {
            "Ah": 579231.188,
            "epoch_timestamp": 1719579017,
            "uniqueID": "11998"
          }
        },
        {
          "timestamp": "28/06/2024 14:55:00",
          "values": {
            "Ah": 579287.25,
            "epoch_timestamp": 1719579315,
            "uniqueID": "11998"
          }
        },
        {
          "timestamp": "28/06/2024 15:15:00",
          "values": {
            "Ah": 579512.25,
            "epoch_timestamp": 1719580515,
            "uniqueID": "11998"
          }
        },
        {
          "timestamp": "28/06/2024 15:20:00",
          "values": {
            "Ah": 579568.5,
            "epoch_timestamp": 1719580815,
            "uniqueID": "11998"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "meter": "230502390",
      "records": [
        {
          "timestamp": "28/06/2024 14:35:00",
          "values": {
            "Ah": 105266.406,
            "epoch_timestamp": 1719578252,
            "uniqueID": "12007"
          }
        },
        {
          "timestamp": "28/06/2024 15:00:00",
          "values": {
            "Ah": 105313.219,
            "epoch_timestamp": 1719579749,
            "uniqueID": "12007"
          }
        },
        {
          "timestamp": "28/06/2024 15:05:00",
          "values": {
            "Ah": 105322.656,
            "epoch_timestamp": 1719580051,
            "uniqueID": "12007"
          }
        },
        {
          "timestamp": "28/06/2024 15:10:00",
          "values": {
            "Ah": 105332.094,
            "epoch_timestamp": 1719580354,
            "uniqueID": "12007"
          }
        },
        {
          "timestamp": "28/06/2024 15:15:00",
          "values": {
            "Ah": 105341.5,
            "epoch_timestamp": 1719580654,
            "uniqueID": "12007"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "meter": "230502756",
      "records": [
        {
          "timestamp": "28/06/2024 13:45:00",
          "values": {
            "Ah": 359171.719,
            "epoch_timestamp": 1719575130,
            "uniqueID": "11999"
          }
        },
        {
          "timestamp": "28/06/2024 14:00:00",
          "values": {
            "Ah": 359340.906,
            "epoch_timestamp": 1719576028,
            "uniqueID": "11999"
          }
        },
        {
          "timestamp": "28/06/2024 14:15:00",
          "values": {
            "Ah": 359511.094,
            "epoch_timestamp": 1719576927,
            "uniqueID": "11999"
          }
        },
        {
          "timestamp": "28/06/2024 14:35:00",
          "values": {
            "Ah": 359612.312,
            "epoch_timestamp": 1719578128,
            "uniqueID": "11999"
          }
        },
        {
          "timestamp": "28/06/2024 14:55:00",
          "values": {
            "Ah": 359803.344,
            "epoch_timestamp": 1719579328,
            "uniqueID": "11999"
          }
        },
        {
          "timestamp": "28/06/2024 15:15:00",
          "values": {
            "Ah": 359994.25,
            "epoch_timestamp": 1719580529,
            "uniqueID": "11999"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "meter": "230507737",
      "records": [
        {
          "timestamp": "28/06/2024 13:45:00",
          "values": {
            "Ah": 6778.53,
            "epoch_timestamp": 1719575142,
            "uniqueID": "12000"
          }
        },
        {
          "timestamp": "28/06/2024 14:00:00",
          "values": {
            "Ah": 6778.969,
            "epoch_timestamp": 1719576040,
            "uniqueID": "12000"
          }
        },
        {
          "timestamp": "28/06/2024 14:15:00",
          "values": {
            "Ah": 6779.408,
            "epoch_timestamp": 1719576940,
            "uniqueID": "12000"
          }
        },
        {
          "timestamp": "28/06/2024 14:35:00",
          "values": {
            "Ah": 6779.994,
            "epoch_timestamp": 1719578141,
            "uniqueID": "12000"
          }
        },
        {
          "timestamp": "28/06/2024 14:55:00",
          "values": {
            "Ah": 6780.58,
            "epoch_timestamp": 1719579340,
            "uniqueID": "12000"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "meter": "230508550",
      "records": [
        {
          "timestamp": "28/06/2024 13:45:00",
          "values": {
            "Ah": 20626.322,
            "epoch_timestamp": 1719575155,
            "uniqueID": "12001"
          }
        },
        {
          "timestamp": "28/06/2024 14:00:00",
          "values": {
            "Ah": 20634.303,
            "epoch_timestamp": 1719576053,
            "uniqueID": "12001"
          }
        },
        {
          "timestamp": "28/06/2024 14:15:00",
          "values": {
            "Ah": 20641.393,
            "epoch_timestamp": 1719576952,
            "uniqueID": "12001"
          }
        },
        {
          "timestamp": "28/06/2024 14:35:00",
          "values": {
            "Ah": 20649.031,
            "epoch_timestamp": 1719578153,
            "uniqueID": "12001"
          }
        },
        {
          "timestamp": "28/06/2024 14:55:00",
          "values": {
            "Ah": 20658.49,
            "epoch_timestamp": 1719579353,
            "uniqueID": "12001"
          }
        },
        {
          "timestamp": "28/06/2024 15:10:00",
          "values": {
            "Ah": 20667.916,
            "epoch_timestamp": 1719580256,
            "uniqueID": "12001"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "meter": "230512323",
      "records": [
        {
          "timestamp": "28/06/2024 13:30:00",
          "values": {
            "Ah": 177571.828,
            "epoch_timestamp": 1719574342,
            "uniqueID": "12006"
          }
        },
        {
          "timestamp": "28/06/2024 14:35:00",
          "values": {
            "Ah": 177815.391,
            "epoch_timestamp": 1719578239,
            "uniqueID": "12006"
          }
        },
        {
          "timestamp": "28/06/2024 15:00:00",
          "values": {
            "Ah": 177909.016,
            "epoch_timestamp": 1719579737,
            "uniqueID": "12006"
          }
        },
        {
          "timestamp": "28/06/2024 15:05:00",
          "values": {
            "Ah": 177927.828,
            "epoch_timestamp": 1719580038,
            "uniqueID": "12006"
          }
        },
        {
          "timestamp": "28/06/2024 15:10:00",
          "values": {
            "Ah": 177946.703,
            "epoch_timestamp": 1719580340,
            "uniqueID": "12006"
          }
        },
        {
          "timestamp": "28/06/2024 15:15:00",
          "values": {
            "Ah": 177965.578,
            "epoch_timestamp": 1719580642,
            "uniqueID": "12006"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

I then have this spec:
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "readings": {
        "*": {
          "meter": "[&1].meter_serial",
          "records": {
            "*": {
              "values": {
                "epoch_timestamp": "[&4].&",
                "uniqueID": "[&4].copper_id",
                "Ah": "[&4].ah"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

Which gives me this result:
[
  {
    "meter_serial": "02319771",
    "epoch_timestamp": [
      1719578227,
      1719579724,
      1719580326,
      1719580628
    ],
    "copper_id": [
      "12005",
      "12005",
      "12005",
      "12005"
    ],
    "ah": [
      4350.947,
      4353.141,
      4354.023,
      4354.465
    ]
  },
  {
    "meter_serial": "02383367",
    "epoch_timestamp": [
      1719575171,
      1719576070,
      1719576969,
      1719578170,
      1719579369,
      1719580273
    ],
    "copper_id": [
      "12002",
      "12002",
      "12002",
      "12002",
      "12002",
      "12002"
    ],
    "ah": [
      2969.499,
      2969.719,
      2969.938,
      2970.231,
      2970.524,
      2970.745
    ]
  },
  {
    "meter_serial": "02383567",
    "epoch_timestamp": [
      1719575210,
      1719578210,
      1719579708,
      1719580310
    ],
    "copper_id": [
      "12004",
      "12004",
      "12004",
      "12004"
    ],
    "ah": [
      45957.805,
      46004.711,
      46028.102,
      46037.508
    ]
  },
  {
    "meter_serial": "02383735",
    "epoch_timestamp": [
      1719576015,
      1719576914,
      1719577815,
      1719578116,
      1719579017,
      1719579315,
      1719580515,
      1719580815
    ],
    "copper_id": [
      "11998",
      "11998",
      "11998",
      "11998",
      "11998",
      "11998",
      "11998",
      "11998"
    ],
    "ah": [
      578668.312,
      578837.062,
      579006,
      579062.25,
      579231.188,
      579287.25,
      579512.25,
      579568.5
    ]
  },
  {
    "meter_serial": "230502390",
    "epoch_timestamp": [
      1719578252,
      1719579749,
      1719580051,
      1719580354,
      1719580654
    ],
    "copper_id": [
      "12007",
      "12007",
      "12007",
      "12007",
      "12007"
    ],
    "ah": [
      105266.406,
      105313.219,
      105322.656,
      105332.094,
      105341.5
    ]
  },
  {
    "meter_serial": "230502756",
    "epoch_timestamp": [
      1719575130,
      1719576028,
      1719576927,
      1719578128,
      1719579328,
      1719580529
    ],
    "copper_id": [
      "11999",
      "11999",
      "11999",
      "11999",
      "11999",
      "11999"
    ],
    "ah": [
      359171.719,
      359340.906,
      359511.094,
      359612.312,
      359803.344,
      359994.25
    ]
  },
  {
    "meter_serial": "230507737",
    "epoch_timestamp": [
      1719575142,
      1719576040,
      1719576940,
      1719578141,
      1719579340
    ],
    "copper_id": [
      "12000",
      "12000",
      "12000",
      "12000",
      "12000"
    ],
    "ah": [
      6778.53,
      6778.969,
      6779.408,
      6779.994,
      6780.58
    ]
  },
  {
    "meter_serial": "230508550",
    "epoch_timestamp": [
      1719575155,
      1719576053,
      1719576952,
      1719578153,
      1719579353,
      1719580256
    ],
    "copper_id": [
      "12001",
      "12001",
      "12001",
      "12001",
      "12001",
      "12001"
    ],
    "ah": [
      20626.322,
      20634.303,
      20641.393,
      20649.031,
      20658.49,
      20667.916
    ]
  },
  {
    "meter_serial": "230512323",
    "epoch_timestamp": [
      1719574342,
      1719578239,
      1719579737,
      1719580038,
      1719580340,
      1719580642
    ],
    "copper_id": [
      "12006",
      "12006",
      "12006",
      "12006",
      "12006",
      "12006"
    ],
    "ah": [
      177571.828,
      177815.391,
      177909.016,
      177927.828,
      177946.703,
      177965.578
    ]
  }
]

However I'm looking to get something more like the below. Timestamp is ignored as I have that in the values data as epoch. There are a lot more values in the "values" arrays but for the sake of this I've limited them. Most are renamed, which is also why they are specifically extracted from the JSON.
[
  {
    "meter": "02319771",
    "Ah": 4350.947,
    "epoch_timestamp": 1719578227,
    "copper_id": 12005
  },
  {
    "meter": "02383367",
    "Ah": 2969.499,
    "epoch_timestamp": 1719575171,
    "copper_id": 12002
  }
]


You can use the following spec :
[
  {//partition by indexes of the arrays respectively by &4_&2
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "readings": {
        "*": {
          "records": {
            "*": {
              "values": {
                "@3,meter": "&4_&2.meter",
                "Ah|epoch_timestamp": "&4_&2.&",
                "uniqueID": "&4_&2.copper_id"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {//get rid of the object keys
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "[]"
    }
  }
]

